# ¿Como comparar cadena con formato String en JAVA?

Tags: java

Para explicar mejor mi pregunta, necesito validar el formato de una cadena de caracteres por ejemplo:

el usuario deberia ingresar en el campo de texto: 6412365-4
valido que el numero sea correcto aplicando el modulo 11.

pero quiero que si el usuario ingresa: 24563254
me envie un mensaje ya que el formato debe ser 0000000-0

¿como comparar el valor ingresado con el formato que necesito?

Comment: Hola Josue, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Depues has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: No es mejor utilizar una máscara para que el usuario ingrese el número con el formato adecuado?

Comment: Pues estamos acostumbrados a lidiar con usuarios como si fuesen niños de 5 años, es decir abarcar la mayor cantidad de casos de error posible, se le puede sugerir al usuario el formato correcto con el cual ingresar, pero que siempre sigan las indicaciones es el verdadero asunto.

Answer (score 2):

este tipo de problemas se afrontan mejor usando expresiones regulares:

```
import java.util.regex.*;


public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Pattern patron = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{1}");
    Matcher mat = patron.matcher("6412365-4");
    if(mat.matches()){
        System.out.println("FORMATO CORRECTO");
    }else{
        System.out.println("FORMATO INCORRECTO");
    }
  }
}
```

Te recomiendo investigar y usarlos

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, esta respuesta era lo que necesitaba.

Comment: @JosuéMartínez si la respuesta resolvió su problema , no dude en marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: El regex se puede acortar un poco a `"\\d{7}-\\d"`

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo completo, el cual te valida si contiene o no el formato que tienes arriba. incluye el guión y tambien el tamaño del mismo.

public class Formato {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String dato;
    int posicion = 0,size=0;
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


    try {
        System.out.println("ingrese el dato");
        dato = bf.readLine();
        posicion = dato.indexOf("-");
        size = dato.length();
        System.out.println("rrr"+posicion+" "+size);
        if(size == 9){
            if(posicion == 7){
                System.out.println("formato correcto: "+dato);
            }else{
                System.out.println("no tiene el formato correcto. 0000000-0");
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("faltan carácteres en el string");
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Formato.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `indexOf` retorna un `int` no un `boolean` , además no creo que valide el formato de la pregunta.

Comment: cierto gracias, por la correcion.

Answer (score 0):

Para validar datos con un patrón determinado puedes usar el java **regex**

Aquí te añado un ejemplo:

```
        String pattern  = "[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{1}";

        String verdadero = "6412365-4";
        String falso = "923412-3";
        String false2 = "1231234-99";
        String falso3 = "64123653";

        ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        lista.add(verdadero);
        lista.add(falso);
        lista.add(false2);
        lista.add(falso3);
        for (String reg : lista){
            if (reg.matches(pattern){
             // Haz lo que quieras aquí
           }

        }
```

> Estoy recorriendo un *bucle for* solo para el ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Hola Josué tu pregunta no la entiendo bien, lo que entiendo es que quieres que el usuario ingrese un valor con un formato con una cantidad de números establecida y al final del último número tenga "-1". Es decir quieres que la cadena
¿1234567-8 sea válido, sin embargo el número 12345678 no sea válido?
la solución sería aplicar un JFormatteTextField. Aquí hay una guía de como usarlo, espero te sea de ayuda.
http://www.chuidiang.org/java/ejemplos/JFormattedTextField/EjemplosJFormattedTextField.php

Comment: Entendiste bien la pregunta, exactamente asi se desea que aparezca

Comment: El detalle es que estoy trabajando en un entorno de java EE, y busco la forma de validarlo en un controlador. pero ya reviso tu información para verificar si encuentro algo de utilidad, de todas formas gracias